# AutoLayout - Won't compress view width

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have two subviews :

- A button (with a fixed width of 30px)
- A content view (with no fixed width)

With AutoLayout, I want the contentView to be compressed so that button view is shown and right margin is respected.

I'm using this VFL :

```
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(==halfMargin)-[contentView][favBtn(==favBtnSize)]-(==halfMargin)-|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:viewsMetrics
                                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
```

But AutoLayout says he's "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

```
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178293a10 H:[UIView:0x17019c150]-(0)-[UIButton:0x12d628890]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178293a60 H:[UIButton:0x12d628890(30)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178293ab0 H:[UIButton:0x12d628890]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x17019c150 )>"
```

Why doesn't he simply compress contentView?

Comment: The first constraint looks like the one between contentView and favBtn, but if you look at the last constraint, it's saying that the superview (the "|") is the same view as contentView (notice the addresses for the UIView are the same for the first and last constraints). So, what is "self" in your code? Is it contentView? It shouldn't be; it should be the superview of contentView and favbtn.

Comment: Have you also tried setting the view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false?

Comment: @rdelmar You spotted the bug! self was indeed the superview of contentView, but not of my button, which was added as a subview of contentView. Argh, I'm really new to "AutoLayout". Since this question has zero added-value for StackOverflow, should I delete it?